# Is ThreadAbortException to be expected in a HTTP handler on Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, httphandler

I have an ASP.NET HTTP handler hosted on Windows Azure in a "small" compute instance. It handles downloads and uploads of large binary files. Nothing else runs within that web role, and there are 2 instances configured, as per guidelines. When a download is done from a computer with a slow connection and I try to perform several downloads at once to choke the bandwidth on the client side, sometimes I get a `ThreadAbortException` in the handler, most often during a `.Write` to the `Response.OutputStream` (I set `Response.BufferOutput = false` beforehand). The stack trace is as follows:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdExplicitFlush(IntPtr context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
   at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MyHandler.ProcessGetRequest(HttpContext context)
   at MyHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

(the `Stream.Write` call is apparently inlined so it does not show in the stack trace).

Why is the thread being aborted? I am guessing I am hitting some kind of a timeout (possibly a socket write timeout), is aborting the thread a normal way for the ASP.NET runtime to handle it?

Note that it is a single HTTP handler, not an .aspx/.cshtml page or MVC controller, and nowhere in my code am I touching `Response.End`, `Response.Redirect` or `Server.Transfer`.

Comment: ThreadAbortedException is a general exception that in general does not tell where exactly the problem is. Please try to let the code expect occasional unexpected exceptions, and retry the action if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whe you upload big files, IIS tries to read request stream and if it blocks for over 5 minutes it would cause IIS to eventually throw ThreadAbortException.

Try playing with this line:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

Also try these suggestions: http://cutesoft.net/forums/permalink/77440/77438/ShowThread.aspx#77438